# Find locus of $z$, where $z$ satisfies $\arg \frac{(z- z_1)(z_2 - z_3)}{(z - z_3)(z_2 - z_1)} = \pi $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to find the locus of the point $z$, satisfying

$$\arg \frac{(z- z_1)(z_2 - z_3)}{(z - z_3)(z_2 - z_1)} = \pi $$

Can anyone please extensively describe how one should tackle these kind of problems?

Comment: Are $z_1,z_2,z_3$ fixed numbers in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Since opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral add up to $180^o$, $z$ lies on the circumcircle of the triangle formed by the points $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$

Comment: Yes..........@user170231

Comment: That's a [Moebius Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) which is a **basic transformation** in the complex field.

Comment: @G Cab One can say even more : it is a real  cross ratio which characterizes a circle : see paragraph "concyclicity" in this [reference](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumbersGeometry.shtml).

Comment: @G Cab Besides, a message of sympathy to our italian friends in these harsh times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $w= \frac{(z- z_1)(z_2 - z_3)}{(z - z_3)(z_2 - z_1)}$. Then, the given condition $\text{arg}(w) = \pi$ implies $w = \bar w =r e^{i\pi}$, or

$$\frac{(z- z_1)(z_2 - z_3)}{( z -z_3)(z_2 - z_1)} 
=\frac{(\bar z- \bar z_1)(\bar z_2 - \bar z_3)}{(\bar z - \bar z_3)(\bar z_2 - \bar z_1)}$$

Use the shorthand $a = (z_2 - z_3)(\bar z_2 - \bar z_1)$
to rearrange above equation as follows,

$$a(z- z_1)(\bar z - \bar z_3)=\bar a( z -z_3)(\bar z- \bar z_1)$$

$$a[|z|^2- (z_1\bar z + \bar z_3z)+z_1\bar z_3]
-\bar a[|z|^2- (z_3\bar z + \bar z_1z)+\bar z_1 z_3]=0$$

$$|z|^2- \frac{az_1-\bar az_3}{a-\bar a}\bar z -\frac{a \bar z_3-\bar az_3}{a-\bar a}z
=\frac{\bar a\bar z_1 z_3 - a z_1\bar z_3}{a-\bar a}$$

Recognize that above $z$ satisfies the equation of a circle, i.e.

$$\left| z - c\right|^2
=r^2$$

with
$$c=\frac{az_1-\bar az_3}{a-\bar a},\>\>\>\>\>\>\>r^2=\left|\frac{az_1-\bar az_3}{a-\bar a}\right|^2+\frac{\bar a\bar z_1 z_3 - a z_1\bar z_3}{a-\bar a}\tag 1$$

Thus, the locus of the point $z$ lies on the circle with its center at $c$ and its radius $r$ given by (1). (See the graph below.)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, by I find your answer very complicated compared to that of Evgeniy...

Comment: @JeanMarie - I interpreted the problem as finding the explicit locus, including the actual center and the radius of the circle.

Comment: The locus of a circle is $|z|^2 + \bar a z + a\bar z +b=0$. Your equation doesn’t seem to satisfy that

Answer (score 4):

Note, that $$\arg \frac{b}{a} = \arg b - \arg a = \angle (Ox, b) - \angle (Ox, a) = \angle (a,b)$$ is the directed angle between vectors $a$ and $b$. From this we have $$\arg \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_3} + \arg \frac{z_2-z_3}{z_2-z_1} = \angle (\vec {Z_3Z},\vec{Z_1Z}) + \angle (\vec {Z_1Z_2},\vec{Z_3Z_2}) = \pi$$
which means, that point $Z$ lies on the arc $Z_1Z_3$ of the circle $Z_1Z_2Z_3$, which contains point $Z_2$.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\arg\Bigl( \frac{z_1-z}{z_3-z} \Bigr)+\arg\Bigl( \frac{z_3-z_2}{z_1-z_2}\Bigr)=π$$
Sum of angle about $z_2$ and $z$ is $π$.
Hence locus of $z$ is arc of circle opposite to $z_2$ with respect to chord joining $z_1$ and $z_3$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?@mathsdiscussion.com

Comment: First of all I can not understand how you write $\arg XY  = \arg X + \arg Y$?@mathsdiscussion.com

Comment: You can check the properties of argument in this link.     https://youtu.be/DJL_UlTu6xU.  Also can check in https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/best-iitjee-maths-for-mains-and-advance/